# I'm trying 2 create a slideshow in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create an automatic slideshow in HTML and JavaScript, but the code is making my entire webpage blank.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Page title</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="4.css">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="landing slides">
  <div class="slides">
   <img src="effiel tower.png" alt="">
   <img src="Capetown.png" alt="">
   <img src="china mountain.png" alt="">
   </div>
 </div>
```

The images on the HTML are working fine, but as soon as I enter the JavaScript code it gives me a blank page.

```
 <script>
window.onload = function(){
var index = 0;
show ();
function show(){
 var i;
 var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
 for(i=0;i<slides.length; i++){
  slides[i].style.display ="none"
 }
 
 index=index + 1;
 if(index>slides.length){
  index=1;
 }
 
 slides[index-1].style.display = "block";
 setTimeout(show, 1500);
}
}
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("slides"); selects the parent div not the img elements.

Answer (score 1):

you selected the parent of the images. It means you are hiding parent. Not images. add class to your images and select them by getElementsByClassName.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. U mean I should add another div class to d image that is  for example "div class= slideshow", n dat I would have replaced my "slides" in my "getElementByClassName with slideshow?

Comment: No. I mean put a class to img tag for example <img class="slide-item" src="..." /> and then change your script selector like this:  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide-item");

Answer (score 0):

```js
let index = 0;
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slides > img');

function showSlideAt(index) {
  for(let i=0;i<slides.length; i++){
    const slide = slides[i];
    slide.style.display = i === index ? "block" :  "none";
  }
}

showSlideAt(0);

setInterval(() => {
  index = (index + 1) % slides.length;
  showSlideAt(index);
}, 1500)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Page title</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="4.css">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="landing slides">
  <div class="slides">
   <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/12a357d653e4cf98f3d3f06f122c2c1f?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG" height="100">
   <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fd4522e30ca42954b37fcc3b4072c3f9?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" height="100">
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```